# Question regarding the syntax of SQL Triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I want to create a trigger that, after an insert on a particular table, there are 2 conditions, where if the first condition is true, it does an insert, and if the second condition is true, it does an update.

something of the sort:

```
create trigger nameoftrigger

after insert on a

for each row
condition regarding newrowattribute and a.sameattribute

insert into a ---

condition regarding newrowattribute and a.sameattribute

update a different table with same attributes
```

but I am not aware of the proper syntax to do this, to check for 2 different conditions and performing an insert in the first condition and an update on the second condition.

Comment: I advice you to [read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide us with example data and expected results

Comment: say we have 3 tables
Table 1 has number column, and we want that if a tuple was inserted into table 2 with the attribute referencing table 1, which is number, that this number updates something in table 3

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support "INSTEAD OF" triggers like Microsoft SQL Server's.

An INSERT trigger can either do an insert, or else it will abort and do nothing.

You should handle your conditions in your application code.

---

Raymond Nijland reminds me that you also can't write a trigger that does any INSERT or UPDATE on the table for which the trigger was executed. Well, you can create such a trigger, but it will generate an error when it executes.

```
mysql> create trigger nameoftrigger after insert on a for each row 
  insert into a values (1);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into a values (2);
ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'a' in stored function/trigger because 
it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Comment: is it possible to make two if statements with different conditions in the trigger body?

Comment: “An INSERT trigger can either do an insert, or else it will abort and do nothing.“ You sure? Because i’am pretty sure a INSERT trigger in MySQL also supports UPDATE or DELETE statements not using the same triggered table name ofcource.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, to do that, it would have to succeed in the INSERT that spawned the trigger. You can do subordinate DML in a trigger, but you can't do that _and_ cancel the original action that spawned the trigger.

Comment: Yes indeed ive might misunderstood the topicstarter question and this anwser. The topicstarter should provide example data and expected results

Answer (score 0):

See `IF ... THEN ... ELSE ... END IF` for the control flow.

If you are *modifying* what you are about to insert, then do something like

```
IF (...) 
THEN
    SET NEW.col1 = <<some expression>>;
END IF
```

then simply let the `INSERT` happen.

If the IF expression or the expression for col1 needs to look at the value that the `INSERT` had for col1, then refer to that as `OLD.col1`.